# MongoDB fails with "fdatasync: Invalid argument" on WSL

Tags: mongodb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am setting up a MongoDB instance on WSL. When I try to run `mongod --dbpath /path/to/db`, I get the following error:

```
E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (22) [1585749233:781695][842:0x7f8f57ee09c0], connection: __posix_sync, 108: /path/to/db: directory-sync: fdatasync: Invalid argument Raw: [1585749233:781695][842:0x7f8f57ee09c0], connection: __posix_sync, 108: /path/to/db: directory-sync: fdatasync: Invalid argument
```

MongoDB creates files in the specified directory, and if I try again, I get

```
E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1585750028:645900][846:0x7f3f0e0309c0], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /path/to/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1585750028:645900][846:0x7f3f0e0309c0], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /path/to/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
```

Can anyone explain the problem?

MongoDB v4.0.3

Comment: MongoDB [requires](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#fsync-on-directories) support for fsync() on directories.

Comment: Does it mean I can not run it on wsl in any way?

Comment: Microsoft says there is at least partial support for fsync, so there might be some magical combinations of version or filesystem that would work (drives that are shared in any way are unlikely to work).  You might also just try running mongod on windows.